# Empty line missing in example in Advanced Links section on Markdown help page

Tags: bug, markdown, editing-help

The example in [Advanced Links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#advanced-links) looks:

```
Here's a <span class="bg-black-200">[poorly-named link](http://www.google.com/ "Google")</span>.
Never write "[click here][^2]".
Visit [us][web].
  [^2]: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere
        (Advice against the phrase "click here")
  [web]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/ "Meta Stack Exchange"
```

which renders to:

> Here's a [poorly-named link](http://www.google.com/).
> Never write "[click here](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)".
> Visit [us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).
> [^2](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere): http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere
> (Advice against the phrase "click here")
> [web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/): https://meta.stackexchange.com/ "Meta Stack Exchange"

With an empty line between text and link definitions it renders correctly to:

> Here's a [poorly-named link](http://www.google.com/).
> Never write "[click here](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)".
> Visit [us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Nice catch :)..